# Open page in a new tab from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, client-server

Does anybody know how to open an URL in a new tab from C# code?
I have tried with

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href('../Documents/doc.pdf','_blank'); </script>");


Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('../Documents/doc.pdf','_blank'); </script>");

Response.Write("$('#pageContent_Send').click();");
```

with

```
$("#pageContent_Send").click(function () {
        window.open("../Documents/doc.pdf");
        return false;
    });
```

and it did not work, using "window.open" I get an "Pop-up Blocker" browser warning.

Comment: Just say Allows popups temporarily and it should work ... You see the popup beccoz new window was opened

Comment: You can't "open new tab from C# code", the c# code runs server side, which is a totally different computer from the client that runs a web browser. And you cannot directly do it in javascript either (you get the popup blocker warning in any decent browser), you can only open a new tab as a response to a user action such as click.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for opening a new tab that won't get blocked.

1. You can have it open the URL with an anchor click, like so `<a href="<url>" target="_blank">click me</a>`
2. You can submit a form to a blank target, giving a similar result, but from a form.  This is useful if you need to post, but can also be useful for get.  Like so `<form method="get" action="<your destination>" target="_blank"><button type="submit">Click Me</button></form>`
3. You can use JS with `window.open` but it has to be tied to an active click event.  I see in your original post that this got blocked, but if you're triggering it on a click event directly (i.e. not using a setTimeout or an async call or something else that delays the window opening) then this should work in all browsers.  Since you're trying to "fake" it by forcing a click, the browser is going to block this every time unless you explicitly allow it.

Comment: It's best to not phrase an answer as a question.  If you have a question, post a comment.  If you are going to post an answer you should be confident enough that it is correct to post it as a declaration.

Comment: No, what I need is to open the new page on a new tab after executing server side code, so, when the user presses the button, the server side code must run, if it runs successfully, then the new page should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='www.xyz.com' target='_blank'>Click me to open me in new tab</a>
```